# Include an HTML menu with correct menu item highlighted

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have some JSP pages in which I want to include an HTML menu (FYI: Bootstrap is being used).

The menu that I want to include consist of three items and its code is shown below. I want to include it in the jsp pages page1.jsp , page2.jsp and page3.jsp. As you can see page 1 is highlighted (set to active) in this example.

How can I make it dynamic so that the correct menu item is being highlighted depending on which of jsp pages that is used?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could use the request.getServletPath() or request.getRequestURI() to find out which page was requested.  Then you could do something like meskobalazs posted in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Scriptlets

You should store your actual page to a variable at the start of the page, like

```
<% String page = pageContext.getAttribute("page"); %>
```

Then you may do this:

```
<li class="<% page.equals("page1") ? "active" : "" %>">Page 1</li>
<li class="<% page.equals("page2") ? "active" : "" %>">Page 2</li>
<li class="<% page.equals("page3") ? "active" : "" %>">Page 3</li>
```

However using scriptlets is not very advisable in modern applications, you may use e.g. JSTL templating to make dynamic pages.

### Using JSTL templates

First we import the core JSTL taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Here we set the page variable to the `page` variable (this comes from a bean):

```
<c:set var="page" scope="session" value="${page}"/>
```

Then finally we make a conditional for the variable:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${page eq "page1"}">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

If you want to go this way, I don't actually recommend exactly this approach, as it could be expressed more concisely, however I myself do not know JSTL extensively.

A shorter but dirtier approach (I did not test this):

```
<li class="<c:if test="${page eq "page1"}">active</c:if>">
    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
</li>
```

Comment: When I try to print the content of the page variable I write: <%=pageContext.getAttribute("page") %>

Comment: And what does it print?

Comment: Then "null" is printed. How do I make the variable contain the page name you are currently in e.g. page1? OBS: Print means, write on the screen so I can see it's value.

Comment: Well, to help you, please include your servlet code in the question. You should define your variable there.